# Control of 12V stepper motor using L293D dual H-bridge

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor, l293d

I've been trying to get a new 12V stepper motor to turn using the circuit below. I connected the 12V to the IC but this led to my Arduino smoking and burning out.[image: L293D circuit with stepper motor]

I'm thinking that the 12V is being pushed into the Arduino due to the common ground or my wiring is wrong. Should this circuit work be safe or will it burn out another Arduino if I connect it up again?

Comment: Do you have pins 5,12,13 connected to ground and a heatsink as the datasheet says??

Comment: Are 4 Gnd inputs 4,5, 13,12 connected?

Comment: No, I've only connected pin 4 to ground as this works with other motor circuits I've tried and tested. In my past experience, not all GND pins need to be connected to ground.

Comment: Did you connect clamp diodes and motor?

Comment: No clamp diodes but 2 motors were connnected

Comment: You better get diodes

Comment: Would 1N4001 diodes work okay?

Comment: If you are using the L293D ...then you don't need external clamp diodes ....they are built-in.  A 12 V stepper motor has very high resistance windings ...are you sure your a high voltage version?? Do you have a datasheet for your stepper?

Comment: Were you in fact using the L293DD rather than the L293D?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: "In my past experience, not all GND pins need to be connected to ground".

This is a very, very bad assumption. You are dealing with a switched high-current inductive load. You will get sharp voltage spikes during switching. GND is very critical. Take a look at the layout example from the TI datasheet below. See the crazy number of GND vias recommended for pins 4, 5, 12 and 13? And yet you have several not even connected.

These pins are probably GND for each push/pull output. By failing to GND these pins, you are forcing the GND current to go through a longer, higher impedance internal path and you are probably getting severe voltage spikes on the internal IC GND which can then cause the IC to latch up, and/or inject spikes into your digital 5V rail.

[image]

Comment: You are controlling a lot of current....all the time!  You need the heat sinking, too.  Is the L293D getting hot?

Comment: The circuit is working now with the clamp diodes added and all pins brought to GND, thank you all. I'm not using heat sinking as the IC is not getting hot, only warm.